# Set a default value to the model being passed to Partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view that is called from another partial view (kind of nested partial views).

The outer partial view is called Company and the inner partial view is a custom control called searchHelp. Both accept a parameter.

Now the Company view gets a parameter of type company and searchHelper accepts an optional string. This part works fine as I am testing the model value for null and assigning is default text as `@((Model==null)?"Enter Text":Model)` when used in other views even without passing a parameter.

In my case of nested views, if I dont provide a string as model for searchHelper then it takes  `company` as model from the outer view i.e company and gives an error.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: not being able to set the default value of the string like we do while calling a function if no value was passed.
this is what i have put in the view @model string
but i need something like this to work ` @model string="Default string"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a default value to the string-as-model from where it's called in the view:

```
//null coalesce to default string value:
@Html.Partial("searchHelp", Model.searchHelp ?? "default value")
```

...though you might do better using an htmlhelper, where you can define the default value just one time:

```
public IHtmlString SearchHelp(this HtmlHelper html, string searchHelp = "default value")
{
    // make html here
}
```

Then

```
@Html.SearchHelp(Model.searchHelp);
```

Comment: Thanks you for the replies.
That works fine.
Although i thought there was way to set default value in razor

Answer (score 1):

The `@model` definition is not a value setter, it's merely telling Razor what type of view to instantiate. You can't define a default value here. If you don't pass a model to your partial, then it will use the model of the parent view, which is `Company` in this case. `Company` is not a string, obviously, so you get that error. If you want to pass a default value for the partial, do that in the second parameter to `Html.Partial`:

```
@Html.Partial("searchHelp", Model.SomeStringProperty ?? "Enter Text")
```